# ajax post to url and refresh 2 data in my html?

Tags: jquery, ajax

First, my coding is like below:

let'say in my php: `$ruser[uuplvlneed] = '500'; $ruser[ulevel] = '5';`

In my html like:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".viewe{$_G[timestamp]}").click(function() {
        var url = "plugin.php?id=jnship:acdo%26do=viewlevel";
        var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: decodedUrl,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
                jQuery("#ulevel").html(html);
            }  
        });
        //code above is work
        //code below i would like to update the exp data in my html, I please help me for correct $ruser[uuplvlneed] data
        var url2 = "plugin.php?id=jnship:acdo%26do=viewexp";
        var decodedUrl2 = decodeURIComponent(url2);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: decodedUrl,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html2){
                /* how to modify here to let me update $ruser[uuplvlneed] data */
            }  
        });
        jQuery("#ulevel").attr('title', 'EXP need: {$ruser[uuplvlneed]}');
    });
});
</script>
<div title="EXP need: {$ruser[uuplvlneed]}" id="ulevel">{$ruser['ulevel']}</div>
```

Above coding is my learn from web, but I don't know how to ajax refresh the `$ruser[uuplvlneed]` data.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot update server php variable from browser javascript, i think you have some big misunderstanding what client-server relation is.
You can pass data from server to client via ajax and then update somethink with this data on client side.

Comment: maybe my english is not well, what I mean is, at the `var2` is my request the latest data for `{$ruser[uuplvlneed]}`, if the `html` is `999` so `{$ruser[uuplvlneed]} = '999'`, the div should be `<div title="EXP need: 999" id="ulevel">5</div>`. can you catch my means? thank you.